# Reactive rest client headers injection in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am following the guide of the new `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` extension to use it in an existing Quarkus application deployed in production.

In the `Custom headers support` section it's introduced the `ClientHeadersFactory` interface to allow injecting headers in a request, but you are forced to return a sync response. One can not use `Uni<MultivaluedMap<String, String>>`, which is of what is desired in my case, because I need to add a token in the header, and this token is retrieved by a request to another rest endpoint that returns a `Uni<Token>`.

How can I achieve this in the new implementation? If not possible, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use `Uni<MultivaluedMap<...>>` in `ClientHeadersFactory` in Quarkus 2.2.x (and older versions). We may add such a feature in the near future.

Currently, you can `@HeaderParam` directly. Your code could probably look as follows:

```java
Uni<String> token  = tokenService.getToken();
token.onItem().transformToUni(tokenValue -> client.doTheCall(tokenValue));
```

Where the client interface would be something like:

```
@Path("/")
public interface MyClient {

    @GET
    Uni<Foo> doTheCall(@HeaderParam("token") String tokenValue);

}
```

Comment: Feature request was created here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20001

Comment: This can also be tried for now https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-client#accesstokenrequestfilter

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that you could just use the header as method arg. Now I can call my API without injecting `ClientRequestFilter`. Thanks.